# Singularities of symmetric product

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a nodal curve over a field $k$ with at least one node. Let $S_d(C)$ be its $d$-th symmetric product. Is it true that the singularities of $S_d(C)$ live in codimension at least 2? My impression is that if $p$ is a node and $p_1,\dots,p_{d-2}$ are smooth points then for example the class of $(p,p,p_1,\dots,p_{d-2})$ gives a singular point and this is a subscheme of codimension 2 because I can vary $p_1,\dots,p_{d-2}$. But I am not sure about the case in which $p$ is a smooth point nor how to prove it.

Comment: When $p$ is smooth, the class of the point $(p, p, p_1, \dots, p_{d-2})$ you consider is smooth because the symetric product of a smooth curve is smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the singular locus has codimension $1$. Indeed, if $p_1,\dots, p_{d-1}$ are pairwise distinct smooth points, and $p$ is a node,  then $(p, p_1,\dots, p_{d-1})$ is singular  in $C^d$. As the stabilizer at this point is trivial, $C^d\to S_d(C)$ is unramified at this point, so its image is singular in $S_d(C)$.

Now obviously, the set of these images, when $p_1, \dots, p_{d-1}$ vary, contains an open subset of dimension $d-1$.

You could check the case $d=2$ to convince youself.

Comment: ok, how do the singularities look like? normal?seminormal?

Comment: Certainly not normal (already false when $d=1$, and the singular locus is too big anyway). The normalization of $S_d(C)$ is the symetric product of the normalization of $C$. From this you could probably deduce $S_d(C)$ is seminormal, but I am not familiar with this notion.